# What are some informal ways to make money with mobile development?

Tags: programmer, money

I'd like to know what the best way(s) to make money with mobile development.

Some developers have already told me that it'd be making building mobile apps to prospective customers.

As a second option, I think I can try to build a very useful app as a startup and market it as effectively as I can. For instance, I'm enjoying studying Android development but I have doubts about how make real good money as freelancer in the mobile development field.

As a third option, I think after getting some real skillsets in Android development, I could try to produce some courses on Udemy.

I'm interested in what advice you have for my predicament. So far I wish to work strictly informal (no contracts).

Comment: I would always suggest being formal about making money. If you want to be informal, simply do projects for friends without money.

Comment: Did you mean friends without much money right?

Comment: To elaborate a bit more about what @David R said. Even if you want to charge your friend for a small or a symbolic amount of money. You should always, consider the formality. Cause, that's something that will protect you as a freelancer in case something goes wrong. Besides that, formality provides trust, and trust --> long time costumer relationships.

Answer (score 3):

I'd seriously consider being formal when money is involved. This will not only protect you and what you'd be being paid, but also the person who would be utilizing your services, as they would, as [Danger mentions](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/10229/what-informal-ways-to-make-money-with-mobile-development#comment12650_10229), have an increased sense of trust in your work. The formality will show them that you fully plan on completing whatever your set task was.

Barring that, if you're exploring mobile development as a hobby, consider writing up an app that you feel has a targeted use for more than just yourself and close friends, and making it public. Whether it's a tool or a game, ensure it's got value to the broader public, then do as your initial thought was, and market it. You could also take on personal projects for friends, provided they're willing to pay you and you're *good* friends with them, and ensure you meet the goals for the project in a timely fashion.

This should really get your foot in the metaphorical door of mobile development and allow you to solicit feedback about your work, and it might earn you some money along the way if you choose to monetize said app. You should be able to determine from this point if you'd like to start making more formal strides as a mobile dev freelancer, and if you do, definitely start approaching it as professionally as possible. When money is involved, and it's not a deal between friends, you should be certain to be as professional as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Sourcing clients/projects, bidding, and sending proposals takes a lot of time. Working for an employer can be a nice last-resort play if you're hurting for money, but I think it's quickly becoming a legacy option.

In my opinion, a mix of options from the following list should keep most developers of any level well-paid and relatively stress-free:

- [Sub-Contract for an agency](https://wilmoore.medium.com/generating-income-sub-contracting-as-a-software-developer-8e4c687f43e2)
- [Technical Writing](https://whopaystechnicalwriters.com/?)
- Software Development [Bounties](https://gitcoin.co/bounties/funder) & [Grants](https://gitcoin.co/grants/)
- [Teach on Skillshare](https://www.skillshare.com/teach)

EDIT (2021-11-15): FYI; this advice works for every type of development. In terms of writing, there are a lot of technical writing opportunities and tons of Web3 companies are providing grants for content marketing projects, documentation, demos, and software that incorporates their blockchain network or wallet SDKs. Teaching on skillshare can also provide some longer-term passive income.